# Show div on li hover jQuery html

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

So it's all together possible that I've just been looking at this for too long but I've debugged all my code and searched everywhere I know for an answer.

Maybe this isn't possible, I'm not sure but here's what I'm trying to do. I have unordered list displayed horizontally acting as my top level navigation. when I hover over one of the items I want to show a div that is the full width of the unordered list above it. here's my caveat: I'm using wordpresss custom post type to do this. the unordered list is the title of the post and I want to show the content in the div that is revealed on hover. I have this working the content loading that's not the issue, i can't seem to find the right jquery / css combination to make the div that reveals match the width of the whole list. I might have to use ajax? Not sure, I'm very unfamiliar with it.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu-header-container"> 
<ul>
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'menu',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'offset' => 0,
'order' => 'ASC'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <div class="overlay">
                <ul>
                    <li><?php the_field('sub_menu_item_one'); ?></li>
                    <li><?php the_field('sub_menu_item_two'); ?></li>
                    <li><?php the_field('sub_menu_item_three'); ?></li>
                    <li><?php the_field('sub_menu_item_four'); ?></li>
                    <li><?php the_field('sub_menu_item_five'); ?></li>
                    <li><?php the_field('sub_menu_item_six'); ?></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </li>
<?php endwhile;?>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu-header-container{
overflow: visible;
float: right;
margin-top: 4%;
}
.menu-header-container > ul > li{
margin-left: 20px;
display:inline-block;
float: right;
}
.overlay{
display: none;
position: absolute;
background: aqua;
}
```

**jquery**

```
<script>
$(".menu-header-container li").hover(function(){
$(this).find(".overlay").stop().fadeIn();
},function(){
$(this).find(".overlay").stop().fadeOut();
});   
</script>
```

**output**

```
<div class="menu-header-container"> 
<ul>
            <li>
        <a href="#">Top Level one</a>
            <div class="overlay">
                <ul>
                    <li>item in sub div</li>
                    <li>item in sub div</li>
                    <li>item in sub div</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">Top Level two</a>
            <div class="overlay">
                <ul>
                    <li>item in sub div</li>
                    <li>item in sub div</li>
                    <li>item in sub div</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle with my output as the html, so i want those top level items on the same line and I want the revealing div to span the whole width of the top level ul and my brain is fried.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8RTTB/)

Answer (score 1):

on the li click event add this `$('#yourDivId').show();`

Answer (score 0):

Give the li tags ids and using jquery

```
$('#liId').click(function() {
  $('#divId').css('display': 'none');
});
```

Or you could create a function that toggles the div display proporty on and off when you click the corresponding li

```
$('#liId').toggle(function() {
  $('#divId').css('display': 'none');
}, function() {
  $('#divId').css('display': 'block');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/8RTTB/1/)

**css**

```
ul,li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li{
    list-style-type:none;
}
```